# Error 70 Excel 2013 while counting files - Not opening files, just counting

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that works fine on other machines, especially Excel 2010 on Win XP SP3 at my office. However, trying to run the exact same code on my Win 8.1 laptop with Excel 2013, I keep getting an "Error 70: Permission Denied"

I've researched, the majority of discussions focus on attempting to access open or locked files. In this case, I'm counting files and subfolders.

The complete code is here:

```
   Option Explicit

Private FSO As Object
Private cFiles(1 To 3) As Long
Private cFolders(1 To 3) As Long

Sub Folders()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim iStart As Long
    Dim iEnd As Long
    Dim fOutline As Boolean

    cFiles(1) = 0: cFiles(2) = 0: cFiles(3) = 0
    cFolders(1) = 0: cFolders(2) = 0: cFolders(3) = 0
    Set FSO = CreateObject("SCripting.FileSystemObject")
    sFolder = "N:\E-Pros Admin\NEW HUB\Division 4 Order Processing\Contracts\CONTRACTS PRIOR TO 05-07-14\"
    SelectFiles sFolder
    MsgBox "# of files: " & cFiles(1) & vbNewLine & _
    "# of folders with files: " & cFiles(2) & vbNewLine & _
    "# of folders with no files " & cFiles(3) & vbNewLine & _
    "# of folders: " & cFolders(1) & vbNewLine & _
    "# of folders with subfolders: " & cFolders(2) & vbNewLine & _
    "# of folders with no subfolders: " & cFolders(3)
    Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub

 '-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub SelectFiles(Optional sPath As String)
     '-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim oSubFolder As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object

    If FSO Is Nothing Then
    End If

    Set oFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)
    cFiles(1) = cFiles(1) + oFolder.Files.count
    If oFolder.Files.count > 0 Then
        cFiles(2) = cFiles(2) + 1
    Else
        cFiles(3) = cFiles(3) + 1
    End If

    cFolders(1) = cFolders(1) + 1
    If oFolder.SubFolders.count > 0 Then
        cFolders(2) = cFolders(2) + 1
        For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
            SelectFiles oSubFolder.Path
        Next
    Else
        cFolders(3) = cFolders(3) + 1
    End If


End Sub
```

The code that throws the error is in the following function/code:

```
Sub SelectFiles(Optional sPath As String)
         '-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        Dim oSubFolder As Object
        Dim oFolder As Object

        If FSO Is Nothing Then
        End If

        Set oFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)
        cFiles(1) = cFiles(1) + oFolder.Files.count   **<== This line throws Error 70 Permission Denied**
        If oFolder.Files.count > 0 Then
            cFiles(2) = cFiles(2) + 1
        Else
```

I have checked all permissions, DCOM both 32 and 64 bit, have all permissions maxed out for Excel (Everyone can access everything, but still no go. Completely frustrated.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks, Jeff

Comment: Try to run Excel as Administrator or check with folder that you have full access to.

Comment: Hi theghostofc, have already tried this as well. The funny thing is that it works great at my office over the network, but can't run on my own local machine where I am the only user and administrator.

Comment: Which is the content of `sPath` when the error is thrown? If it is `N:\E-Pros Admin\...`, are you sure, that you can open this path in windows explorer from your home local machine?

Comment: As pointed by @AxelRichter, please see if the path is valid on your home system also.

Comment: The commented out "N:\..." is a network location at my office. I added a browser chooser to pick the folder, but no matter what folder you select on the home system it throws the error on that line.

I believe it is this:

**'oFolder.Files.count'**

that is causing the error as the previous 2 arrays have values, some of the time.

Hope this helps, cause I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The so called "junction points" NTFS "Symbolic Links" are to blame for this errors. 
See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930128/en

I tried it with my Windows 7 system. It is *not* updated from Windows XP. Nevertheless there are such junction points for example `"C:\Users\axel\Documents\Eigene Bilder"`. If the FSO gets such junction point as `Folder` object, it gets a Folder object with blank `Files` collection without any methods or properties. Same for the `SubFolders` collection. But they are not Nothing. They are Objects. If the program tries to access those collections, the `Error 70 "Access denied"` is thrown.

As a solution you could use `On Error Resume Next` before access to .Files and .SubFolders with possible such junction points and `On Error Goto 0` after the access. But the junction points will not be counted.

Greetings

Axel

Comment: Thanks Axel!  Okay, makes sense. Didn't even think about simple Error processing to get it over with.. I"ll check it out.